# Operations `CREATE TRIGGER` and `CREATE PROCEDURE` in ANSI SQL

Tags: stored-procedures, triggers, ansi-sql

I need to know a syntax of `CREATE TRIGGER` and `CREATE PROCEDURE` operations in **ANSI SQL standard**. But as I know each databases use a custom SQL syntax in some details, so I don't know that is from all variants is ANSI SQL. And I can't find ANSI SQL standard docs (in any case in public access).
Can someone tells me where I can find it? Or which database uses a correct syntax to read its docs?
**P.S.** I am a nobie in SQL just I need it for my exams. At work I used PostgreSQL always but I noticed that it is not same like ANSI SQL.